# random sample on SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql, sample, random

I have a table with a column called names, it is meant for there to be several rows with the same name. I need to find a way to make a query to give as result a 4% random sample of the rows with every name. For example, if there are 100 rows of each name in the table, for it to return 4 random rows for each name on that column. Does that make sense?

This is how my table looks like:

```
Id    name   order_id
1     john   10
2     mike   11
3     jay    12
4     john   13
5     jay    14
6     mike   15
*     
*
25000 jay    25010
```

And for results I need a random sample of 4% of john's order_ids plus a 4% random sample of jay's order_ids and so on. (Hope this makes it clear)

I posted this same question but for Access SQL, however I was able to figure out a couple of things in order to use regular SQL.I'm not very experienced on SQL, yet. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL

```
SET @skip=1; 
SET @numrows=(select count(*) * 0.04 from test );
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT distinct names FROM test order by rand() LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```